# There's an un-explainable gap is coming in my design for mozilla browser

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am facing some problem in my design. There's an un-explainable gap is coming.

It is working fine in google chrome browser but not working in mozilla and internet explorer 10.

link for the page is https://www.zenkast.com/new-home

the gap is below "Zenkast rewards your prediction skills" text, and the portion has red border.

Please if anyone can help me in this issue.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: @Paulie_D Tough to find the code responsible for causing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like an issue with the responsive video being floated (taken out of document flow) by its parent bootstrap column. Adding the following will fix it:

```
  .videodiv > div {float: none;}
```

Comment: Thanks.. this code works....

Comment: @user3557006 Did you see my answer?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like an *explainable* gap. `:P` Give this to solve the issue:

```css
.row.videodiv::before {display: block;}
.row.videodiv {display: block; overflow: hidden;}
```

It is caused by the `clearfix` not working. Alternatively, consider removing the `float` to the `<div>` inside `.videodiv`:

```css
.videodiv > div {float: none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add clear: both to the div.row.videodiv!

try the code bellow

```
    <div class="row newblock">
        <h2 class="header">Lets do predictions! We have got prizes for you</h2>
        <h3 class="contentlabel" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">Zenkast rewards your prediction skills</h3>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="row videodiv" style="clear: both;">
                .......................
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Or add this css rule

```css
div.row.videodiv {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Hey.. your code worked. but the gap was still there..  But Thanks...

Comment: add overflow:hidden to the div parent
<div class="row" style="overflow: hidden;">
            <div class="row videodiv" style="clear: both;">
                .......................
            </div>
        </div>